# How to get previous date in aix with given value?

Tags: shell, date, aix

I want to get the previous date in AIX environment.
But it seems date -d commands can't work. And I only found 
yesterday=`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d`  as solution.

However, this raise me the timezone problem and I don't know how to solve it.

And I tried  these commands, but it gives wrong date in some time period. (e.g. today is 20190418 07:01:19, yesterday will be 20190416 23:01:19)

```
today=`date +%Y%m%d`  
yesterday=`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d` 
yesterday=`TZ=$TZ+24 date +%Y%m%d`
```

I echo my #TZ and it is HKG-8.I know that I can use +16 to force this become my answer. But it's not work if the timezone is changed.
Can anyone suggest any solutions for get previous date of a date value or simply any ways to solve time zone problems?

Comment: Either install GNU-dateutils, or replace the missing funcionality if date(1) with some program (Perl-script, for example).

Comment: For an example, I created an example script: https://github.com/lzsiga/pldate usage: `perl pldate set 19680101 add-days -1` result: `19671231`

Answer (score 0):

This sample script can help you:

```
date +%s|awk  '{printf "%s\n", strftime("%c",$1-86400)}'
```